# Proper MIME media type for TAR files

Tags: http-headers, mime-types, content-type, tar

When working with TAR files, I've run across the MIME type

> application/x-tar

However I am not sure it is right, because

> MIME types in the x- namespace are considered experimental

and it seems odd to me for venerable TAR.

Are there any recent RFC about MIME and TAR ?
And what's about widespread HTTP server and browsers support ?

Comment: There are commonly used standardized MIME types that still use `x-`. For example, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. There have been many MIME types for TAR:  `application/tar`, `application/x-tar`, `applicaton/x-gtar`, `multipart/x-tar`, `application/x-compress`, `application/x-compressed`.

Comment: Mime types for `.tar.gz` include `application/gzip`, `application/x-gzip`, `application/x-gtar`, and `application/x-tgz`.

Comment: Remy, I am talking about uncompressed archives. For compressed ones, it isn't so simple, see http://serverfault.com/questions/304361/how-can-i-define-a-mime-type-in-nginx-for-tar-bz2-or-tar-gz-files/516095#516095

Comment: 6 may 2020 : IANA still doesn't speak about TAR : https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The **MIME type** for an uncompressed TAR file as mentioned in Wikipedia is **application/x-tar**.

Refer:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_archive_formats

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but wikipedia is not the official source. MIME types have been officially registered with IANA.

Comment: @Massimo but not for TAR, as you mentioned a few minutes ago in another comment. There is no *official* registered media type for TAR, but `application/x-tar` is *commonly used*, which I mentioned in my comment *4 years ago*.

Comment: Mozilla also lists `application/x-tar` as "common": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types. For browsers at least, this should be a good reference.